# Установка OpenGL и OpenAL в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, qtcreator

Какие для этого надо скачать библиотеки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем то смысл прост, берешь и действуешь через терминал:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenal1 libopenal-dev
sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev
```

---

теперь расшифруем какие библиотеки для чего:

`sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev` для OpenGL
`sudo apt-get install libopenal1 libopenal-dev` для OpenAL
`sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev` для ALUT

---

После проделанных действий вводим в терминале команду:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator libglfw3-dev libglm-dev libepoxy-dev libboost-all-dev libglew-dev libopenal-dev libalut-dev
```

*И незабываем прикреплять к "проектам" библиотеки :3*